# How to have IN operator work to have hard coded values match

Tags: sql, postgresql, in-clause

```
Have accountId ={001,3456,78902,456}
```

I wanted to get the details of these `accountId` from existing table using  `IN` clause and a `left join on` operation, how should I form the query? Being new to DB end I am not able to put the correct pieces together:

```
select t1.col2, case when CASE WHEN t1.col3 is null THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END as value
FROM table2 t2 left join table1 t1 on t2.col1=t1.col1
WHERE accountID IN (001,3456,78902,456); //The query is wrong because, I wanted to map using those accountID and get the data?
```

Any quick help on forming the query would be great

The Existing table have `accountId` as one of the columns.

Comment: `accountid` is part of which table? Always provide table definitions and your version of Postgres with questions like that. And an explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing ...

```
SELECT t2.col1, t1.col2, (t1.col3 IS NULL) AS value
FROM   table2 t2
LEFT   JOIN table1 t1 USING (col1)
WHERE  t2.accountid IN (1,3456,78902,456); -- t1 or t2 ???
```

I added `t2.col1` or you might get rows with only `NULL` values.
Using the simpler `(t1.col3 IS NULL) AS value` which returns `boolean` `TRUE` / `FALSE` directly.
Also using the simpler `USING` to join on a column of the same name.

If `accountid` is in table1 as well, you don't need to join at all ..

```
SELECT t1.col2, (t1.col3 IS NULL) AS value
FROM   table1
WHERE  t1.accountid IN (1,3456,78902,456);
```